# C# Program: File I/O randomly slower on x64

Tags: c#, sql-server, io, x86, 64-bit

I have a program that has two different modes, standalone mode, and a client-server mode. Part of the automated testing framework for it does testing for file imports/exports of data that the program calculates, it times the imports/exports over say 100 iterations and compares the time result to some baseline results.

The testing framework will test on x86 for both the standalone and the primary, and then on the x64 for both.

Lately, I've been running into a peculiar problem where 3 of these 4 tests pass, but for 1 of them it fails. This 1 that fails is always x64, and the most interesting part is that which one of the x64 tests fails depends on the order they are run in, i.e. if the x64 test for standalone runs first and the client-server runs second, the client-server ends up taking substantially longer, but if I switch the order, it will be the standalone that takes substantially longer.

The second point of interest is that this issue is sporadic, i.e. over the last 6 days, 2 of the times it managed to fall within a decent range of the baseline, but the other times it was well over.

I considered that it may be due to resources used at a specific time on the hardware, so I disabled everything I could including search indexing, and switched the order so that the x64 tests run when the x86 tests used to run and vice versa, but the x86 tests passed in the new time slot no problem, while the x64 tests continued to fail in the x86 timeslow.

To further bypass possibly hard drive problems I also started to only time importing/exporting to a stream, rather than to a file, but that made no difference.

I'm baffled as to what could be causing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running separate processes or are these tests all run inside 1 application?

Comment: All these tests are running inside one application, one at a time.

Comment: Then one test leaking memory or resources will slow the rest down. So it could be your resource management.

Comment: Running the program does not seem to result in any memory leaks, but you're right it would be worth investigating. The part that gets me as why it only happens on the 2nd of two x64 tests. If there was a resource management issue, I feel like it should be exposed elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you captured the Performance Counters (`perfmon.exe`) while running the tests? I would check things like the GC counters, CPU etc.

Comment: Hi Chris, I haven't tried checking that yet. I'll do that and get back to you, thanks!